# How to insert a loop into a code below

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<div class="content">
                <h1>Fotoalbum rybníka <span>Fotky roka 2013/2015</span></h1>
                <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
                    <div class="rg-thumbs">
                        <!-- Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                        <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                            <div class="es-nav">
                                <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                                <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="es-carousel">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="Kapitálne úlovky - Štuka" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-large="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="Kapitálne úlovky - Kapor" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-large="images/3.jpg" alt="image03" data-description="Kapitálne úlovky - Kapor" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-large="images/4.jpg" alt="image04" data-description="Násada - Amur" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" data-large="images/5.jpg" alt="image05" data-description="Násada - Amur" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/6.jpg" data-large="images/6.jpg" alt="image06" data-description="Úlovky rybárov" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" data-large="images/7.jpg" alt="image07" data-description="Násada - Kapor" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" data-large="images/8.jpg" alt="image08" data-description="Násada - Kapor" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" data-large="images/9.jpg" alt="image09" data-description="Západ slnka z prostredia rybníka" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" data-large="images/10.jpg" alt="image10" data-description="Rybolov" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/11.jpg" data-large="images/11.jpg" alt="image11" data-description="Rybolov" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/12.jpg" data-large="images/12.jpg" alt="image12" data-description="Správcovia rybníka" /></a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/13.jpg" data-large="images/13.jpg" alt="image13" data-description="Úlovky rybárov - 2,5kg šťuka" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/14.jpg" data-large="images/14.jpg" alt="image14" data-description="Úlovky rybárov - 5kg kapor" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/15.jpg" data-large="images/15.jpg" alt="image14" data-description="Úlovok 8-ročného rybára - 6,5kg šťuka" /></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                    </div><!-- rg-thumbs -->
                </div><!-- rg-gallery -->
                <p class="sub"></a></p>
```

This code stands for galery on my page. I wanna ask how to insert a loop there so I don't need to write `<li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" ...` all the time. Image index is always incremented by +1.

In c++ it would look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
    LoadImage("images\thumbs\" + i + ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this php code between `ul`

```
    <ul>
           <?php
                $totimg = 15;
                for ($i=1; $i<=$totimg; $i++) {
                   echo '<li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/'.$i.'.jpg" data-large="images/'.$i.'.jpg" alt="image14" data-description="Úlovok 8-ročného rybára - 6,5kg šťuka" /></a></li>';
                }
           ?>        
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In php

```
$totalImages = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalImages; $i++)
    echo '<img src="images/thumbs/' . $i . '.jpg/>';
```

Comment: You didn't close the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing PHP

```
 <div class="es-carousel">
     <ul>
        <?php
            $descriptions = array ( 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'Desc3', ... );
            $numImages = count($descriptions);
            for ($i=0; $i<$numImages; i++) 
               echo '<li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/'.$i.'.jpg" data-large="images/'.$i.'.jpg" alt="image0'.$i.'" data-description="'.$descriptions[$i].'" /></a></li>';
         ?>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: What would be the reason to output the same image 100 times in a row?

Comment: Sorry the answer got posted before I was even remotely finished. Somehow hit wrong button combination when I was editing the code.

Comment: Note that the `data-description` would need to be held in an array or something like that. `data-description="'.$descriptions[$i].'" />`